# Any software that can model eddy currents?

Tags: software-recommendations, one-topic-per-answer, electronic-transport, metals, magnetic-field

Is there any software on metals that can predicts orbital or induced currents in metals in the presence of a magnetic field or electromagnetic waves?

Comment: If my answer solved your question, could you please click on the tick mark next to it and mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found couple of tools online. Here I collate the ones I think are relevant:

- [MEMEP3Dtool](https://github.com/epardov/MEMEP3Dtool):
  Three-dimensional (3D) electro-magnetic modeling tool for superconductors and normal conductors using the Minimum Electro-Magnetic Entropy Production (MEMEP) variational principle. (1)
- [MaxFEM](https://www.usc.es/en/proxectos/maxfem/description.html):
  This [paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-02949-8_16) shows examples of how to use MaxFEM for analysis of eddy currents. (2)
- [QuickField](https://quickfield.com/index.htm):
  Here is an [example](https://quickfield.com/advanced/hmagn5_induction_pump.htm) to simulate eddy currents in a liquid metal on the QuickField website. Quickfield has a free "student" edition. More info [here](https://quickfield.com/free_soft.htm).

---

References:

1. Enric Pardo, Milan Kapolka, 3D computation of non-linear eddy
   currents: Variational method and superconducting cubic bulk, Journal
   of Computational Physics, Volume 344,2017,Pages 339-363, ISSN
   0021-9991, https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcp.2017.05.001.
2. Bermúdez, A., Gómez, D., & Salgado, P. (2014). Eddy currents with maxfem. UNITEXT, 325–345. https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-02949-8_16